# Openquery: The metadata could not be determined because every code path results in an error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have an openquery that isn't working due to the customer upgrading to SQL Server 2012.

The query looks like this:

```
 INSERT INTO [AccountToSync]  
 SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([REMOTESERVERNAME],' SELECT  TOP  1000  
 [column1],[column2],[column3] FROM RemoteDBName.dbo.Account  
 inner join LocalDBName.dbo.CUSTOMER on PRVBRANCH  = CUSBRANCH 
 inner join LocalDBName.dbo.ACCOUNT on PRVBRANCH = ACCBRANCH
 where ACCRECNO > 0 And PRVCODE IN (''DUAL005'', ''ADP'', ''ADPGRP'') 
 and (AccChanged & 1 <> 0 AND AccChanged & 2 = 0)  
 Order By PRVDATEEXPIRES Desc ')
```

And the error message is:

> "The metadata could not be determined because every code path results in an error; see previous errors for some of these."

The cause seems to be that for 2012 onwards I need to put `WITH RESULT SETS` to explicitly specify the result set, but i can't work out how to restructure  the above/insert that into this query.

Can anyone tell me what the query should look like with this in it? Thanks!

EDIT: Solved this. Actually the error message threw me in the wrong direction: the real cause is that the linked-server name is missing from the inner joins.

Comment: Is the remote server SQL Server as well? And is LocalDBName a database on your local SQL server?

Comment: There is NO EXECUTE in your query, how and why do you want to use WITH RESULT SETS?

Comment: Thanks guys; the WITH RESULTS SETS may not be the solution; just a red herring; please see my edit to the original question. Yep LocalDBName  is the name of a database on the local server.

Comment: Do you want to say that RemoteDBName and LocalDBName are not on the same server?

Comment: If the remote server is also SQL Server, it might be easier to just use 4-part names & then you can forego OPENQUERY.